# Generate java.awt.Image using byte[] from oid column in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, itext, seam2

have a nice day. I'm working an application using Seam 2, rich faces and primefaces, Hibernate JPA and PostgreSQL. Previously i have done some catalogs for some tables with an image field. I use those annotations to declare the image field in my table:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "fotografia")
public byte[] getFotografia() {
    return fotografia;
}
public void setFotografia(byte[] fotografia) {
    this.fotografia = fotografia;
}
```

And it stores in a oid column in my table in PostgreSQL database. After that i can show the image without problem in my views using a primefaces tag for showing images:

```
<p:graphicImage id="_ftFur"
                                    value="#{genericImageStreamer.image}"
                                    rendered="#{genericImageStreamer.image!=null}"
                                    alt="Sin fotografia" style="width:320px; height:420px;"
                                    styleClass="ui-image-container" />
```

So it works without problems in my view. But now i need to create a PDF report showing a list of rows from my table and i need to show the image that i stored for each row, but it doesn't work. I use seam itext.

For my code, inside the repeater tag which i use to iterate through ArrayList, i'm trying to use p:image tag with the attribute imageData as shown in the documentation:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{vis.image != null}">
                        <p:image alignment="center" imageData="#{vis.image}" />
                            </ui:fragment>
```

But i always get an error when it's trying to generate the report:

```
 10:06:28,006 ERROR [STDERR] 04-14-2014 10:06:28 AM com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/inv/producto/repVestidosPDF.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:89)
    at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.UIImage.createITextObject(UIImage.java:145)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encodeBegin(ITextComponent.java:213)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encode(ITextComponent.java:283)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encode(ITextComponent.java:295)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encodeChildren(ITextComponent.java:256)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at com.sun.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:50)
    at com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:357)
    at com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:617)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encode(ITextComponent.java:289)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encodeChildren(ITextComponent.java:256)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encode(ITextComponent.java:289)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encodeChildren(ITextComponent.java:256)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encode(ITextComponent.java:289)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encodeChildren(ITextComponent.java:256)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encode(ITextComponent.java:289)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encodeChildren(ITextComponent.java:256)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encode(ITextComponent.java:289)
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.ui.ITextComponent.encodeChildren(ITextComponent.java:256)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

According with seam documentation:

```
p:image inserts an image into the document. Images can be loaded
from the classpath or from the web application context using the value
attribute.
Resources  can  also  be  dynamically  generated  by  application  code.
The imageData attribute can specify a value binding expression whose
value is a java.awt.Image object.
```

And that's what i'm doing, creating a java.awt.Image object using the byte[] matrix that i get from the database. I have tried those lines of code, obtaining the same error message:

```
//1
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
productoIter.setImage(toolkit.createImage(img.get(0).getFotografia()));

//2
Image image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(img.get(0).getFotografia()));
productoIter.setImage(image);

//3                                   genericImageStreamer.setMimeType(img.get(0).getMimeType());
genericImageStreamer.setInputStream(img.get(0).getFotografia());
Image image = ImageIO.read(genericImageStreamer.getImage().getStream());
productoIter.setImage(image);
```

productoIter is an iterator that i use to set the java.awt.Image object, after getting the list from the database, i iterate through it and i try to convert the byte[] to java.awt.Image, but even when the byte[] isn't null, it gives me the previous error. I don't know if i have to convert that byte[] into another thing before using it as a parameter to create the Image object or something like that.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i answer myself because after searching a lot i found a solution to my problem. Basically is about generating a **ByteArrayInputStream** instead a java.awt.Image and then using **value** attribute instead **imageData** in  tag.

Here is the link with the full answer (check the response of the guy that posted that, he answers himself like me). Probably the datatype can be customized if you store the mimetype of the image.

[Show database images into seam itext pdf report](http://markmail.org/thread/mmbyxbha5mtuv7bm#query%3a+page:1+mid%3ammbyxbha5mtuv7bm+state%3aresults)